# unknown gap before input-group-addon in default asp.net mvc 5 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

how to reproduce :

1. create new ASP.Net MVC project
2. add a model
3. add a controller with scaffolding views
4. open the Create.cshtml in browser , then change any "form-group" using firebug or developer tools :

From :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Name">Name</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <input name="Name" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Name" type="text" value="">
   </div>
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name"></span>
</div>
```

To :

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Title">Title2</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input name="Title" class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Title" type="text" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

we just put "input" inside a "div" with "class='input-group'" and added an "input-group-addon"

the result is very weird , it looks like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmq80.png

but the correct result is this :
http://jsfiddle.net/6t3d9z8e/

is this a bug with ASP.Net MVC 5 default template or what ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's interesting bug in interaction between bootstrap css and microsoft default styles.

See in your default css file "Site.css" and remove block after comment `Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default`, where setting `max-width` property on inputs.

And if you want to limit your input by size you should do this by bootstrap's `col-md-...` classes.

Comment: this solved the problem , I commented out this line from "Site.css" :
   
    input,
    select,
    textarea {
        max-width: 280px;
    } , thanks alot

Comment: You could also add this: .input-group
{
    max-width: 350px;
} without commented out the above.

Comment: It is curious that even in the latest versions of Visual Studio have not fixed this bug.

Comment: I wish I found this an hour ago - I was about to throw my PC out of a window. Do you have any idea as to why it is there in the first place? By default, MVC applications use Bootstrap in the first place don't they?

Answer (score -1):

By looking at your screenshots, it is very clear that MVC5 is overwriting the default bootstrap input properties.

Add the below CSS code to your style sheet. This will solve the problem.

```
.input-group .text-box { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because microsoft default style contains block of css, whick set `max-width: 280px`.

Comment: Then Try to overwrite the same from your css. --- .input-group .text-box { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }