# Boostrap css input button addon alignment issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The image attached shows my datepicker button not touching the input inside a bootstrap modal.  I've looked at the css in chrome dev tools and can't find anything significant. I thought it maybe an issue with the input group inside of a formgroup. Any ideas as to whats going on?

**Code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".modal-body", function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $("#datepicker").focus();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add Reminder:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 id="modal-date"></h4><br />
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reminderTitle" class="control-label">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reminderTitle">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datepicker" class="control-label">Date/Time:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reminderComments" class="control-label">Comments:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="reminderComments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveModal()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #datepicker {
        z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found another css thats effecting it... Site.css has this code:

```
input, select, textarea { max-width: 280px; }
```

How can i override this for this particular modal view?

Comment: create fiddle , it may help us in answering that

Comment: this is the best i could do https://jsfiddle.net/b3c6xd6s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer: [unknown gap before input-group-addon in default asp.net mvc 5 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507294/unknown-gap-before-input-group-addon-in-default-asp-net-mvc-5-template)

I commented out my site.css here:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

And added this:

```
.input-group { max-width: 280px; }
```

To make it finally after almost 2 days look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some CSS that we can't see changing the input's width. The icon element is all the way to the right because that's where it should be. Bootstrap form elements have `100%` width by default:

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

You must have something affecting the input width and that is the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/b3c6xd6s/1/

Comment: I found another css thats effecting it... Site.css has this code: input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

Comment: How can i override this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [jQuery ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

The problem i see immediately is how you try to position the datepicker when it shows up.

This css line is wrong:

```
#datepicker {
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Instead try to use [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow):

> For the alignment problem you need to create the evidence with a fiddle or adding your css.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".modal-body", function () {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
      $(input).css("z-index", "999999");
      inst.dpDiv.css({top: ($("#datepicker").offset().top / 2)+ 'px', marginLeft: '0px'});
    }
  });
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    $("#datepicker").focus();
  });
});


// open the modal....
  $("#calendarModal").modal();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="calendarModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Add Reminder:</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 id="modal-date"></h4><br />
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reminderTitle" class="control-label">Title:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reminderTitle">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="datepicker" class="control-label">Date/Time:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Date" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="reminderComments" class="control-label">Comments:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="reminderComments"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveModal()">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```